При просмотре видео на YouTube появляются артефакты
Скажу сразу, в железе очень понимаю. Проблема - при просмотре видео на YouTube появляются артефакты, так, будто очень плохо видеокарте.
Симптомы:


Длится от 5 до 30 секунд*
Имеет разную интенсивность
Появляется раз на 30 - 120 секунд*

*- примерный интервал
С видеокартой всё более менее приемлемо, игры по типу Divinity или Valheim играются без особых проблем, проблем с графикой не обнаружено. На других сайтах подобных проблем не обнаружено, т.е., появляется исключительно на YouTube.
Длится такое примерно года 2. Видна переустанавливалась несколько раз за этот период. Драйвера для видеокарты обновлял, ничего не помогло.
Ноутбук Lenovo Swift L3 на Intel Core I3-1115G4, видеокарта интегрирована - Intel UHD Graphics
Скриншоты с информацией для сисадминов





Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
